# PDOException could not find driver Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, wamp

Hi i want to migrate from sqlite to mysql, i install WAMP server, configure this and work fine, but...

```
 [PDOException]
  could not find driver
```

i see this error when i want

```
php artisan migrate
```

Select PHP: 5.6.25, but on 7.0.10 dont work too

my php.ini from wamp

```
;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
;extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=pgsql.so
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
;extension=php_pgsql.dll
```

my dtabase.php

```
 'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),


    'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver'   => 'sqlite',
            'database' => database_path('database.sqlite'),
            'prefix'   => '',
        ],

        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'mwebsite'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```

and my .env

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_DATABASE=mwebsite
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

//php info
Configure Command

```
cscript /nologo configure.js "--enable-snapshot-build" "--enable-debug-pack" "--with-pdo-oci=c:\php-sdk\oracle\x64\instantclient_12_1\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8-12c=c:\php-sdk\oracle\x64\instantclient_12_1\sdk,shared" "--enable-object-out-dir=../obj/" "--enable-com-dotnet=shared" "--with-mcrypt=static" "--without-analyzer" "--with-pgo"
```

PDO

```
PDO support enabled
PDO drivers mysql, pgsql, sqlite
```

Comment: Is pdo_mysql listed in `phpinfo()` ?

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Wamp versus Xampp.

Example using laravel 5:

```
php artisan migrate:install
```

gives:

> PDOException: could not find driver

Since Wamp has multiple php environments, you must ensure that php paths are correct (including composer php path when switching php versions).

php version used by apache and php cli versions might not be the same, depending on your %PATH% variable.

Probably your php executable path isn't right.
Using cmd, try

```
set | findstr php
```

You'll see where your actual php binary is loaded.
Change your path variable accordingly (using system settings, user profiles, environment variables) and start a new cmd instance. Y

You may then check that pdo_mysql extension is loaded in the current cli version of php using

```
php -i | findstr mysql
```

Once everything is sorted out, don't forget to update composer php path (just reinstall it).